# Know the just incremented value

Tags: mysql, sql-update

We everybody know how to increment a column in MySQL:

update table set col = col + 1 where id = 15;

But ... is there anyway to know the new value WITHOUT doing a SELECT query ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to understand your question.
Taken from [Posted by Justin Swanhart on July 29 2004 5:32pm@Mysql UPDATE refman](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).
Maybe this is what you trying to achieve for

```
update table set 
col = col + 1 
where id = 15
and @value := col
```

> The `@value := col` will always
>   evaluate to true and will store the
>   col value before the update in the
>   @value variable.

You could then do

```
select @value;
```

Comment: What happens when multiple rows are affected by the UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.

If you think about it, since multiple rows could be affected by an UPDATE, it's not trivial nor necessarily attractive to think about the database returning all of that data in the context of an UPDATE.

The MySQL docs also address the "can I do UPDATE and SELECT in the same subquery" question:

> Currently, you cannot update a table
>   and select from the same table in a
>   subquery.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

One alternative that *may* work for you is to rely on the SELECT..FOR UPDATE approach:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html